# Native SQL select forces flushing in transactional method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have a transactional method where objects are inserted. The debugger shows that upon `eventsDAO.save(..)` the actual insert doesn't take place, but there is only a sequence fetch. The first time I see `insert into events_t ..` in the debugger is when there's a reference to the just-inserted Event.

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
public void insertEvent(..) {

   EventsT eventsT = new EventsT();
   // Fill it out...
   EventsT savedEventsT = eventsDAO.save(eventsT);  // No actual save happens here
   // .. Some other HQL fetches or statements ...

   // Actual Save(Insert) only happens after some actual reference to this EventsT (below)
   // This is also HQL
   SomeField someField = eventsDAO.findSomeAttrForEventId(savedEventsT.getId());
}
```

But I also see that this only holds true if all the statements are HQL (non-native).

As soon as I put a Native-SQL Select somewhere before any actual reference to this table, **even if it does not touch the table in any way**, it forces an immediate flush and I see the statement `insert into events_t ...` on the console at that exact point.

If I don't touch the table `EventsT` with my Native SQL Select in any way, why does the flushing happen at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto):

> **6.1. AUTO flush**
>
> By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush in the following circumstances:
>
> - prior to committing a Transaction
> - prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions
> - *before executing any native SQL query that has no registered synchronization*

So, this is expected behaviour. See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_code_auto_code_flush_on_native_sql_query) section. It shows how you can use a synchronization.